# Is it possible malloc() allocates a buffer that overlaps another buffer allocated using mmap()?

Tags: c++, c, malloc, new-operator, mmap

I plan to use mmap() to allocate a buffer close to a specific address.

What I'm worried about is, the buffer allocated using mmap() will overlap other buffers allocated by malloc() or new operator (C++). Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that does not happen.

The heap maintained by the `malloc` function lives in virtual mappings that have been established via `brk` or `mmap`, so memory areas could only be reused if the kernel gave out the same block via `mmap` twice.

Answer (score 6):

If you use `MAP_FIXED` to demand `mmap` create the mapping at a particular address, then **yes it is possible** that you overwrite an existing mapping such as space allocated by `malloc`, part of a shared library's code or data section, etc. Basically it's always an error to use `MAP_FIXED` unless you've already obtained the address range via a call to `mmap` without specifying `MAP_FIXED` (so you know it belongs to you); in this case you can intentionally overwrite parts of the mapping using `MAP_FIXED`).

The other answers all seemed to miss the fact that you said "close to a specific address", which to me implies `MAP_FIXED`. If you're not using `MAP_FIXED`, please elaborate on how you're obtaining a mapping "close to a specific address".

Answer (score 1):

You must allocate the memory that is mapped, with malloc. malloced memory won't overlap. So no, you'll be fine.